# How to use cloud code on parse server with bitnami and AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, bitnami

I recently migrate my parse.com app to from parse servers to amazon AWS using bitnami parse server and mLab.
The migration works OK and the only problem i'm having is with the cloud code.
I edit the main.js located in /bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/spec/cloud
but i don't know how to deploy the file.
how do i update the cloud code file after editing? 
I tried: forever stop 0
forever start server.js, but it didn't work.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Bitnami Parse Server documentation:

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Parse_Server#How_to_start.2fstop_the_servers.3f

After making changes to main.js just run
`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart parse`
to restart the Parse server.

Comment: doesn't work.. i've tried to restart parse using sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart parse many times but still the cloud code wont update...

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is that you might not be editing the cloud code file that the Parse Server is loading. Check `installdir/apps/parse/server.js` to make sure the `cloud` param when initializing the server points the the `main.js` file you're editing. Also, maybe throw in some `console.log(...)` to that file to make sure it's getting loaded.

Comment: I have the same problem, however when I change the server.js file, and change the cloud parameter to point to my main.js it does not work..The cloud parameter is set to point to ./node_modules/parse-server/lib/cloud-code/Parse.Cloud.js and modifying it messes up my website...

Comment: @Meeyam The `cloud` parameter in `server.js` should be pointing to your custom cloud code file **not** any file in node_modules.